# Selected tree nodes are not displayed properly in IE 8

Tags: smartgwt, treegrid

In my application I have implemented Smartgwt TreeGrid with checkbox.

I have used the same code given in Smartgwt Showcase.

http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#tree_checkbox

In Internet explorer 8, when I select any node, the selected nodes are shifted right from its' original place.

In Firefox and Chrome it works fine.

Please help me out in this.

Comment: Is it working fine with other ie versions ?